# Blazor WASM - Assign Identity User to object

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor WASM program that has a `Box` and `Service` model with a one-to-many relationship. Each service has a foreign key to a Box, and each Box has a foreign key to an Identity User. I want to be able to display a list of users in the UI, and allow the user to assign a User to a Box. I was able to successfully create a one-to-many relationship between a User and Box, but I am not sure how to display the users or assign them. For the Box model, I use the `UserId` field as the foreign key, but I want to be able to pass a username "Josh" for example to the model instead of his ID.

**Box Model**

```
public class Box
    {
        public int BoxId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public string Cidr { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
        
    }
```

**Service Model**

```
public class Service
    {
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public int BoxId { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
    }
```

**Application User Model**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: To display the users you just use ```Box.User```. To assign you use the foreign key. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Grizzlly I guess the problem I'm having is to display a list of all usernames in a dropdown, and when a user selects one, it assigns that user to the Box. I am not sure how to connect a user's display name to their ID so I can assign them.

Comment: You dropdown would be based on ```ApplicationUser``` which has both the ID and the display name (or username in this case).

Comment: @Nate... did you get your solution to work?  I have a similar question to get a list of Identity-Users to appear in an <ul> <li> html.  I cannot get to the Identity UserManager from the wasm-Client pages.  Comments?